# What is $\int_0^\infty \int_x^\infty \frac{1}{y} e^{-y/2} \, dy \, dx$?

Tags: definite-integrals

Frankly I don't know how to simplify or which theorem to apply. I do know theorem on $e^{-y^2}$ (gaussian) but I don't think I can manipulate the current question to that form?

P.S Answer is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the order of integration yields

$$\int_0^\infty \int_x^\infty\frac1ye^{-y/2}\,dy\,dx=\int_0^\infty \int_0^y \frac1ye^{-y/2}\,dx\,dy$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: I think you misread the question, the power of $e$ is $y/2$ not $y^{-2}$. I

Comment: @ManishKumarSingh I've edited.

Comment: @Jason I've edited.  But the methodology was not impacted whatsoever.  Only the argument of the exponential function.